# Finding SP chain calls in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, chain

I got these three giant schema in Oracle which I call them db layers (L3, L2, L1).
In each layer I got many SPs which might call some procedures from their underlying layers. Now for documentation purposes I need to draw something like a tree to show these chain calls. Well I'm not interested to get involved in the drudgery of extracting this data manually.

The question is, is there an automated way to do this? like a query to find out who calls who.

[image]

Comment: You could query the dependencies of your procedures from the dictionary, but I don't think you can generate a sequential call diagram solely on Oracle Database. You'll probably depend on a 3rd party solution on this, I'm sure there are PL/SQL code analyzer tools out there.

Comment: If you can extract the metadata then you'll probably find that it's pretty complex, and also changes every time you modify the codebase. I'd recommend using GraphViz to plot the dependencies automatically, so all you need is to have SQL that generates the appropriate format of file, or just the section that contains the relationships. I've done this successfully for DBMS_Scheduler chains, tasks and programs. You can expand the method to include views and tables also.

Answer (score 1):

I was just fiddling around a little. So maybe like a starting point.

Replace DBA_OBJECTS.OWNER IN ('HUSQVIK') with your schemas.

```
WITH leafs AS (
    SELECT
        DBA_OBJECTS.OWNER, DBA_OBJECTS.OBJECT_NAME NAME,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(PARENT_REFERENCES.REFERENCED_NAME) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IS_REFERENCED,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(CHILD_REFERENCES.NAME) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END HAS_REFERENCES
    FROM
        DBA_OBJECTS
        LEFT JOIN DBA_DEPENDENCIES PARENT_REFERENCES ON DBA_OBJECTS.OWNER = PARENT_REFERENCES.REFERENCED_OWNER AND DBA_OBJECTS.OBJECT_NAME = PARENT_REFERENCES.REFERENCED_NAME
        LEFT JOIN DBA_DEPENDENCIES CHILD_REFERENCES ON DBA_OBJECTS.OWNER = CHILD_REFERENCES.OWNER AND DBA_OBJECTS.OBJECT_NAME = CHILD_REFERENCES.NAME
    WHERE
        OBJECT_TYPE IN ('PACKAGE BODY', 'FUNCTION', 'PROCEDURE')
        AND DBA_OBJECTS.OWNER IN ('HUSQVIK')
    GROUP BY
        DBA_OBJECTS.OWNER, DBA_OBJECTS.OBJECT_NAME
)
SELECT 'Entry point -> ' || OWNER || '.' || NAME DEPENDENCY_PATH, 1 MAX_STACK_DEPTH FROM leafs WHERE leafs.IS_REFERENCED = 0 AND leafs.HAS_REFERENCES = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT
    DEPENDENCY_PATH, STACK_DEPTH
FROM (
    SELECT
        'Entry point -> ' ||
        CONNECT_BY_ROOT DBA_DEPENDENCIES.OWNER || '.' || CONNECT_BY_ROOT DBA_DEPENDENCIES.NAME ||
        SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(DBA_DEPENDENCIES.REFERENCED_OWNER || '.' || DBA_DEPENDENCIES.REFERENCED_NAME, ' -> ') DEPENDENCY_PATH,
        CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF ISLEAF,
        LEVEL + 1 STACK_DEPTH
    FROM
        DBA_DEPENDENCIES
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT * FROM leafs WHERE leafs.IS_REFERENCED = 0) roots
        ON roots.OWNER = DBA_DEPENDENCIES.OWNER AND roots.NAME = DBA_DEPENDENCIES.NAME
    WHERE
        DBA_DEPENDENCIES.REFERENCED_TYPE IN ('PACKAGE BODY', 'FUNCTION', 'PROCEDURE')
    START WITH
        roots.NAME IS NOT NULL
    CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
        PRIOR DBA_DEPENDENCIES.REFERENCED_OWNER = DBA_DEPENDENCIES.OWNER AND
        PRIOR DBA_DEPENDENCIES.REFERENCED_NAME = DBA_DEPENDENCIES.NAME)
WHERE ISLEAF = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Get **all dependencies** of your schema with this **query**:

   select  *  from all_dependencies where owner = 'your_schema_name'
2. **Export** result of query to JSON (or any other format).
3. **Process** JSON of dependencies to **generate** tree(s).